# formatting value-ios

Tags: ios

I am working on weather application. I am putting annotation on the map and annotation callout display temp. However once tempertature goes above three digits, it shows three dots instead of value. How could I format the value to display three digits. Any suggestions?

```
int value=[att integerValue];
```

it was:

```
annotation.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ozone Level:%@",value];
```

it is:

```
   annotation.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ozone Level: %@ ",value];
```

Comment: Please don't make significant changes to your question after getting answers, because then our answers make no sense. Stack Overflow is a repository of questions and answers, not a forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers are not pointers, you are trying to use the object specifier (`%@`) instead of the integer specifier:

Try

```
NSInteger value = [att integerValue];
annotation.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ozone Level: %d ", value];
```

Answer (score -1):

The three dots is almost certainly the OS telling you the label isn't large enough to display the full number.  Give the label more room.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's because you didn't actually *change* anything.  You added a single space to the end of text that was already too long for the label.  What you'll need to do is make the actual annotation larger, most likely -- too many variables for me to be more precise (pre defined MKAnnotationView?  Custom annotation view?)